# Submitting code on CodeEval site

Tags: java, unix

A Java program on CodeEval had to accept a file path as an argument. I used a command line argument to do this, but I get an exception as below when I submitted my code on CodeEval. What are some potential solutions to this problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextElement(StringTokenizer.java:407)
    at Main.FileRead(Main.java:61)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the boilerplate Java code that I use for my Codeeval code.  The specific problem code generally goes in the processLine method.  I don't use Scanner or StringTokenizer.  I use the String split method to process the input.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main implements Runnable {

    private String fileName;

    public Main (String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            processFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processFile() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            processLine(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }

    private void processLine(String line) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main(args[0]).run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, Check the name of class.Class name should be 'Main'.
Second you have to give all the imports in CodeEval Editor which you are using in your program.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you don't check to see if there are any more tokens (by calling `hasMoreTokens`). If no more tokens exist and you call `nextToken`, you will get this exception. However, without seeing the rest of your code, there is no way to know what is actually happening.

Comment: No, I am able to run the program correctly from my local. There is no problem reading and processing the file. The problem is that the CodeEval site is not able to access the filepath that is passed as a command line argument. The reason to post this question is to check if there is someone who has uploaded code on CodeEval  and knows how to give an input to the main() in a java program